# ajax, save innerHtml form ajax call for show on Back from Browser

Tags: jquery, browser-cache, innerhtml, back

I need to save the code from my ajax call that is:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
   document.getElementById("return").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
```

for call at "Back" call from browser when I go to another page from this page.
I don't want use **target="_blank"**
I can I do it?
location.hash is not ok because i have not a url with GET parameters

Tnx